# How can I open some ports on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port

I know a little about Linux. Today I created a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) server on my Ubuntu installation according to *[Set up a simple IPsec/L2TP VPN server for Ubuntu, Arch Linux and Debian](https://github.com/philplckthun/setup-simple-ipsec-l2tp-vpn)*.

But when I finish the installation, I use my iPhone to connect the [IPsec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) VPN, bur it shows the VPN Server has no response.

The GitHub document shows

> Ports 1701, 500 and 4500 must be opened for the VPN to work!

So I have tried to open these ports on my Ubuntu server.

I use the [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) command to open these ports, but it failed. Maybe I don't known how to use this command correctly. How can I open these ports on my Ubuntu server?

And if these ports have been opened successfully, can it be proved by the Windows [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) window through [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)'ting the port?

Answer (score 145):

Ubuntu these days comes with [UFW - Uncomplicated Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW). UFW is an easy-to-use method of handling iptables rules.

Try using this command to allow a port:

```
sudo ufw allow 1701
```

To test connectivity, you could try shutting down the VPN software (freeing up the ports) and using [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) to listen, like this:

```
nc -l 1701
```

Then use telnet from your Windows host and see what shows up on your Ubuntu terminal. This can be repeated for each port you'd like to test.

Comment: So what's next if `ufw` didn't open a port -- that is, the output of `sudo iptables -L -n` didn't change?

Comment: @ruffin It looks like you forgot to check [iptables](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/control-network-traffic-with-iptables). Incantation === `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1701 -j ACCEPT` etc.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to open it for a range and for a protocol

```
ufw allow 11200:11299/tcp
ufw allow 11200:11299/udp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can open a port with this command

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

And then check the firewall status with this

```
 sudo ufw status verbose
```