# Unable to connect to localhost on two different machines

Tags: c++, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, grpc

I am running the gRPC C++ helloworld example from the official website ( https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/cpp/). It works just fine when I run the client and server code using two different console windows. The connection fails, however, when I try to run it using two different laptops.

> 14: Connect Failed
>   Greeter received: RPC failed
>   14: Connect Failed
>   Greeter received: RPC failed

On both laptops I am running Ubuntu 19.04 on VirtualBox, and they are connected to the same network. The address I used is the IPv4 address listed under the 
network settings.

I am not sure what is causing the problem. I tried looking up the correct IP address to use in such a case but my efforts were futile. I would appreciate it if I am given some direction on how to proceed.

Comment: Likely culprits are firewalls and antivirus.

Comment: What ports are you using? They could either be alreayd in use or firewalled. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251889/how-to-open-some-ports-on-ubuntu

Comment: To find the ip address of each VM (although you probably just want the server IP), run the following command: `ifconfig eth0` in each of them. You could also try looking at connected devices in your router web interface.

Comment: This is likely a firewall issue. Check iptables rules on your VMs. You can check tcpdump to verify if you're receiving traffic on the server side.