# DJango mail working in local but not in production

Tags: python, django, email, smtplib, django-email

Below is my code which sends a mail to my users:

```
mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject, body=text_content, from_email="email@host.com", to=["email@host.com"], bcc=["email@host.com"])
mail.attach_file(model.document.path)
mail.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
mail_status = mail.send()
```

And my `settings.py` is as below:

```
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.host.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = "email@host.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = str(os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD'))
```

The problem is that the above code works absolutely fine in my local Windows machine but the code hangs and shows no output when running in my remote server running Ubuntu (Linux).

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this will be a port issue. The best way to confirm this is by using  `telnet` client.

```
telnet mail.host.com 587
```

If you are not seeing `Connected` text after issuing this command, then the problem is most likely because of the `port`. In that case you might have to [explicitly open this port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30252006/6699447).